# Choke module in the KNX power supply, what is the purpose of the third winding?

Tags: inductor

I have a question concerning the physical interface of KNX, twisted pair.

I was wondering how the KNX (twisted pair) transceiver can produce a pulse like the following:

[image: KNX-TP pulse waveform]

I thought there must be some sort of inductor or choke in the power supply side, so that it presents a higher impedance at higher frequency. The equalization pulse looks just like the back EMF as we turn off a coil.

Luckily, I found a pic in the KNX standard. (Fig. 12 in ch9-2, basic component)

[image: choke module]

Clearly, W3-4 and W5-6 form a differential (no common) mode choke, which presents a high impedance while current is sunk, also the voltage drop is due to the two 47Ohm resistors.

What I don't understand is the purpose of the third winding, W1-2.

During active pulse duration, point 2 is more positive than point 1 in W1-2, the 220nF capacitor is charged through the diode and 100Ohm resistor.

In the equalization period, the polarity reverses, the PNP BJT turns on and the capacitor 220nF is discharged.

Do I understand this correctly?

What is the purpose of this capacitor charge/discharge action?

How exactly is the waveform related to this choke circuitry?

Can some analog expert shed some light on this?

Comment: A link to the KNX standard or a good reference would be a useful addition to the question.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I've found the specification/standard here,
https://my.knx.org/shop/product?language=en&product_type_category=knx_specifications&product_type=knx-specifications